# Caratheodory's construction

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

My question refers to Federer's book on geometric measure theory, 2.10 Caratheodory's construction around p.169. Basically the question is: "Why is it possible to apply **Caratheodory's criterion** on the measure $\psi=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\phi_\delta$, when it does not apply for any $\delta >0$?"

Consider the open set $(0,\frac{\delta}{2})\cup(\frac{\delta}{2},\delta)$ and the gauge $\operatorname{diam}(A)^\frac{1}{2}$. The set is not $\phi_\delta$ measurable, since Caratheodory's criterion does not hold:
$$\phi_\delta\Big((0,\frac{\delta}{2})\cup(\frac{\delta}{2},\delta)\Big)=\delta^\frac{1}{2}<2 \Big(\frac{\delta}{2}\Big)^\frac{1}{2}=\phi_\delta((0,\frac{\delta}{2}))+\phi_\delta((\frac{\delta}{2},\delta))$$

I am struggling with the right intuition. I see, that "problems" occur for two disjoint open sets $A,B$ with $\operatorname{dist(A,B)=0}$, but in this case I am still wondering how to calculate $\psi(A\cup B)$ in the right way, i.e. as the limit of $\phi_\delta(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Oh, maybe take for open $S$ the coverings $S\subset\cup_{x\in S}B_{\delta}(x)$, while $S\supset\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\cup_{x\in S}B_{\delta}(x)$, since for any $x\in S$ there exists an $\delta$ Ball which is completely in $S$? Then it follows $A\cup B= \lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\cup_{x\in A\cup B}B_{\delta}(x)=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\cup_{x\in A}B_{\delta}(x)\cup \lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\cup_{x\in B}B_{\delta}(x) $ is a disjoint union?

Comment: Even for $\operatorname{dist}(A,B)=0$, right?